# Objective-C sending a message to an object not allocated

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to know if there is any risk in passing a method to an instance that is NOT allocated?  At the moment, the my code seems to work perfectly fine without any warnings.

```
UIView *testview; 
[testview someMethod];
```

This doesn't cause any problem as far as I can observe but wanted to make sure that this is the case.

Comment: No, this is not the case. If a pointer is uninitialized, the its value is indeterminate. Using it invokes undefined behavior. Also, this question is not about Xcode, so you shouldn't tag it as such.

Comment: Better declare the variable like this: `UIView* testView = nil;`

Comment: In the recent versions of the compiler you do not have to declare it like @DanShelly proposed. The pointer also is not "uninitialised", it is nil by default!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passing a message to `nil` is not an error in Objective-C, simply a NOP. However, passing a message to an incorrect address, such as an uninitialized or dangling pointer, *is* an error. Depending on the context where you define your uninitialized variable it may either be implicity initialized to `nil` or then you're just getting lucky with that memory being `nil` *this time*. But for the code to be guaranteed safe, you need to guarantee that it's either `nil` or pointing to a valid object. The simple way to do that is to initialize it explicitly: `UIView *testview = nil;`.

Comment: Note that ARC guarantees that variables will be initialized to nil.